# What is the 'combustion point' of a game? This was in an upvoted answer

Tags: opening, engines, database, terminology

Saw an answer and it had been upvoted. 
Person answering had a large rep on stack.

The term used that was not explained is: 
'Combustion Point' (of a game)

My question is just what does 'combustion point' of a game mean?

Intuitively to a native speaker it would seem to mean something major like a disaster happened.  That does not seem to fit as it was applied to all games around move 26 per the OP it answered.

Comment: I think you should start with asking this as a comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The question you mention is here: [In ChessBase 12, when viewing an Opening Tree, why do all the games always stop near move 26?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5820/in-chessbase-12-when-viewing-an-opening-tree-why-do-all-the-games-always-stop/5824#5824)

Personally, I think it is just a general English statement he used to describe the middle, and most heated analytically, part of the game based on the context. I doubt anyone else would repeat it.

Frankly, if I downvoted a lot, I would probably have downvoted that answer since it does not really begin to answer the question. The real answer is either the user was doing something wrong, and should have been shown how to do it (probably not), or simply that was the way it was in the code because that is where they arbitrarily cut off the opening, and cannot be changed (probably).

P.S. If I were to ever describe a part of a chess game as such, it would be where everything came to a head, and the tactics started to fly.

Comment: Thanks.  Unclear how tactics start to fly in most games.  Some games are wide open slash and burn attack with tactics but many (most?) games are more positional and slow and tactics may happen at some point but not really start to fly as they quickly do what they did and the game resumes at the slower pace with one side having a material advantage.

Comment: Well, IF I were to use that phrase, it certainly would not apply to every game at all...I would only apply it to some tactical melee. He seemed to use it more generally.

Comment: exactly.  which is part of my confusion.  i would have come up with a more general name for the area between opening and uncharted middle game moves.

Comment: I think it was just a poor turn of phrase.

Comment: agreed.  they made up something they thought fit but was not at all widely used nor in this case accurate or useful.